# Detect soft keyboard in Meteor cordova with ratchet

Tags: meteor, ratchet-bootstrap

Meteor now support mobile apps. That's great. However, I find that the app running as a mobile app is not the same as running in a mobile browser.

When it runs as a mobile app, if the user wants to input to a text field, a soft keyboard shows up. Then, after the user finishes and click the button (at that point, the soft keyboard is still shown), the app brings to another page. However, the new page renders as if the soft keyboard still exists so the lower portion of the screen is blank. The elements that are rendered to a fixed position (like footer) still shows up at the bottom though. Even though the lower portion of the screen is blank, the elements are still there. If I tap the blank portion, and if there is a link or button in the place I tap, the app still brings me to the new page. Since I use Meteor and ratchet, I don't know which one is the issue.

I suspect the issue is that when the user clicks the button, the Meteor renders the new page immediately, but the soft keyboard get hidden afterwords.

This situation doesn't happen when the meteor app runs in a mobile browser, however.

I use meteor, iron-router, and ratchet. The issue is identified in an android 4.X device. Any idea how to fix the mobile app specific issue? Thanks.

PS. If I delay firing the page transition by a second, I don't have the issue. So my suspicion is correct that the page transition happens before the keyboard is hidden.

Comment: OK. I kind of find a workaround by performing page transitions described here: [link](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/simple-page-transitions-with-iron-router-hooks). However, the issue is still there. Now the page is first transitioned with the soft keyboard portion blank. Then the page renders the blank portion to the correct content. So I always see a glitch. But it is better than not showing the content at all! I'd prefer to have a clean solution. Such as force the soft keyboard to hide before the transition.

Comment: I created a test case in github: https://github.com/sf-wind/meteor-ratchet-keyboard-issue. It includes the meteor app source code, the generated android app production.apk, and a screenshot.